# li elements not responding to fadein css in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In Firefox it works as intended but in Chrome **li** text is not **fading in**. I've tried grouping everything with **a,li** but it outputs a all li elements with 0.5 opacity, while **a** elements remain correct.

html

```
<h2> Foo  <a href = "http://www.google.com" target = "_blank">Link</a>  </h2>
<h2> Foo2 <a href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com" target = "_blank">Link</a> </h2>
<hr>

<h2>Index</h2>

<ol>
<a href = "#images"><li>photo</li></a>
<a href = "#video"><li>Video</li></a>
<a href = "#videogame"><li>Videogame</li></a>
</ol>
```

and the css

```
li
{
list-style-type:none;
}


a
{
clear:both;
color: #0db9d2;
opacity:1;
-webkit-opacity:1;
-moz-opacity:1;
transition:opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

a:visited{
color: #28548d;
}

a:hover{
opacity:0.5;
-webkit-opacity:0.5;
-moz-opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: The valid structure is `<ol> <li> <a>...</a> </li> </ol>`: http://cssdeck.com/labs/u3bysk03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have the `<li>`  as list inside `<ol>`

```
<h2> Foo  <a href = "http://www.google.com" target = "_blank">Link</a>  </h2>       
<h2> Foo2 <a href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com" target = "_blank">Link</a> </h2>    
<hr>    
<h2>Index</h2>

<ol>
    <li><a href="#images">photo</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#video">Video</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#videogame">Videogame</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/p78t06ta/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the LI-text isn't fading in, is that your CSS selector targets `A`elements in particular. This is why only the text in `A`-elements will fade (the text node in the `LI` element sits outside the `A`)..

Wrapping the `LI`-element inside `A` is illegal HTML syntax as pointed out by zvona, but we can fix that by moving the `A` inside the `LI`.

```
<li><a href="#images">photo</a></li>
```

Here's a fiddle with your code and the syntax changed:
http://jsfiddle.net/erlingormar/hshjydLg/

Is this effect what you were looking for?